# What is the anonymous number displayed during the settimeout function execution in the console?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I tried executing settimeout() function using callback in javascript. An anonymous random number is displaying every time I use it(only in console). I wanna know what it is.

```js
setTimeout(function() {   
      console.log("one");   
      setTimeout(function() {   
         console.log("two");   
         setTimeout(function() {   
            console.log("three");   
         }, 1000);   
      }, 1000);   
   }, 1000);
```

*Execution of the above code gives me a number in console:*

[image: Execution of the above code gives me a number in console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console will display the result of the final expression (*synchronously*) evaluated above. Because `setTimeout` returns a number corresponding to the unique ID of the timeout, that is what the number you're seeing is - the ID of the outermost `setTimeout`.

(This ID is useful to have because it means you can then pass it to `clearTimeout` or `clearInterval` to clear the existing timeout or interval.)

You'd see the same sort of output with this code, where the ID is explicitly assigned to a variable, and then evaluated again on the last line:

```
outerTimeoutId = setTimeout(function() {   
  console.log("one");   
  setTimeout(function() {   
    console.log("two");   
    setTimeout(function() {   
      console.log("three");   
    }, 1000);   
  }, 1000);   
}, 1000);
outerTimeoutId;  // <-- results in some number being displayed in the console
```